# Have a FormType data_class with a DI constructor (Symfony 2.3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

here is my class working with Symfony DI :

```
class Car {

    protected $wheel;

    public function __construct(Wheel $wheel) // We inject the service
    {
        $this->wheel = $wheel;
    }
}
```

I want it to work as `data_class` for a Sf2 FormType :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Car',
    ));
}
```

The problem is here : https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/2.3/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L135-L141

The FormType executes a `new` on the `data_class` (Car) with no parameter, so all the DI stuff is broken.

How can I deal with it ? Is it even possible ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You shouldn't define DI container inside entity class.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152610/get-service-container-from-entity-in-symfony-2-1-doctrine

Comment: Indeed yes, thank you for the note! I'm looking for a workaround to this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to initialize the data class model, and pass it to the form :

```
// Create an instance of the car model
$car = $this->carFactory()->create($wheel);

// Pass it to the form as data while building it
$form = $this->formFactory->create('MyFormType', $car);

// Add the car field
$form->add('car', $car->getFormType(), $car->getFormOptions());
```

This way, the `data_class` is never null, so there is no `new` called by the FormType.